# onclick for p:outputLabel works on loading/refreshing page but doesn't work when clicking

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have some problems with calling a bean method when clicking on Label.
When page is loading or refreshing click handler function pokus() is called, but when the label is clicked it isn't.

Part of my web page:

```
<h:form id="pokus">
  <p:outputLabel id="pokus2" value="klikni" onclick="#pozadavkyBean.pokus(5)}"/>
</h:form>
```

and a method in bean:

```
public void pokus(int i){
    System.out.printf("kliknuto sloupec:%d",i);
}
```

I've also tried it with:

```
<p:ajax event="click" listener="....
```

with the same result - method called on loading/refreshing but not when clicking

also tried others events: mousedown, mouseup, .... with same result

using PrimeFaces 5.0

Comment: 1. onclick should not be used to call actions. 2. #pozadavkyBean.pokus(5)} should be #{pozadavkyBean.pokus(5)} 3. this is wrong use for outputLabel 4. <p:commandLink id="pokus2" value="klikni" action="#{pozadavkyBean.pokus(5)}" styleClass="myAwesomeClass"/> would be better IMHO.

Comment: ad 2. this is evidently a mistake made when writing this topic. I'vejust been lazy to deal with a changes of cursor and a different appearance, it should look just like plain text with no effects, and didn't realize what "Client side calback" stands for. thx for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will check official document of [Primeface](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/outputLabel.html) regarding Tag `outputLabel`.You can easily get attribute `onclick` used for

> Client side callback to execute when component is clicked.

But here you are trying to run Managed bean method directly from `onclick` attribute while `onclick` used to call JavaScript functions.

As **@Mahendran Ayyarsamy Kandiar**  mentioned and its simple thing `outputLabel` is not used to call any bean method. Its Just Simply used to show something in the page.In mean time for your requirement you can use `CommandButton`,`CommandLink` or some other component but its all depend upon your requirment etc.

Comment: I'have checked it, but english isn't my mother tongue and was tired and didn't realise what exactly "Client side callback " means. Thx for explanation and reply.

Comment: @VenaVena I am also same categoty for me Hindi is my Mother Tongue. But its ok Happy to help :)